# Can I run the trigger at the force.com site?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, force.com, force.com-sites

I have a registration page on the site, when i clicked submit, generate a Lead record by trigger, but now does not work.

Comment: Hello Peter, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Can you please **[edit]** your post to be more clear about what you have done so far and what behavior you observe? This level of detail is sparse and will make answers difficult to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to read salesforce's documentation on [triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)

> Apex triggers enable you to perform custom actions before or after
> changes to Salesforce records, such as insertions, updates, or
> deletions.

Basically, this means that your trigger runs on the background, and you specify when a process happens, based on different stages of when a record is processed before being added or removed from the database.

As long as a record is created/deleted from your force.com site, yes a trigger can be executed in the process.

If your tigger/apex code is failing for some reason, please include code snippets along with any error messages that we can use to help you. thanks!

Comment: you are right, My trigger has a logical error, so i cannot update record by trigger.  thanks.